# Adding objects from Parse to array for UITableView Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Im trying populate a UITableView using retrieved objects from Parse.
The items are retuned ok, when I try and use them for my `_appliances` `NSArray` I get:

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Console prints my `_appliances` `array` as:

```
014-07-27 18:24:16.249 myapp[15839:60b] Fan
2014-07-27 18:24:16.249 myapp[15839:60b] kettle 
2014-07-27 18:24:16.250 myapp[15839:60b] Projector
```

viewDidLoad:

```
    PFQuery *queryApplianceClass = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"savedAppliances"];

    [queryApplianceClass selectKeys:@[@"appliance"]];

    [queryApplianceClass orderByDescending:@"updatedAt"];

    queryApplianceClass.limit = 100;

    [queryApplianceClass findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *applianceObjects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {


            for (PFObject *applianceList in applianceObjects) {
                 NSLog(@"%@", applianceList[@"appliance"]); //Prints to console as above

                  //Array of Appliances from database
                 _appliances = applianceList[@"appliance"]; 

            }


        }
        else {

            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
      }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep assigning an `NSString` value to the `_appliances` array variable. I believe you want this:

```
[queryApplianceClass findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *applianceObjects, NSError *error) {
    if (applianceObjects) {
        NSMutableArray *appliances = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (PFObject *applianceList in applianceObjects) {
             NSLog(@"%@", applianceList[@"appliance"]); //Prints to console as above
             //Array of Appliances from database
             [appliances addObject:applianceList[@"appliance"]]; 
        }
        _appliances = appliances;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
  }];
```

Also note that you should only check `error` if `applianceObjects` is `nil`.